# Unable to implement Repository method: IGenericReactorRepository.save(Object entity) for generic repository

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-mongodb

Try to create a generic repository with MongoDb and Microanaut Data.

```
@MongoRepository
public interface IGenericReactorRepository<E, ID> extends ReactorCrudRepository<E, ID> { }
```

The implementation of IGenericReactorRepository

```
@Singleton
public record VendorService(IGenericReactorRepository<Vendor, ObjectId> iGenericReactorRepository) implements IVendorService {
    @Override
    public Flux<FindVendorModel> find(VendorFilterModel searchCriteria) {
        return Flux.just(findVendorModel);
    }
}
```

In the record parameter I have defined entity type and objectId `IGenericReactorRepository<Vendor, ObjectId> iGenericReactorRepository`. The issue is with the `@MongoRepository` annotation on the interface and it creates the below exception

```
Unable to implement Repository method: IGenericReactorRepository.save(Object entity). class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar cannot be cast to class javax.lang.model.element.Element (com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar is in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app'; javax.lang.model.element.Element is in module java.compiler of loader 'platform')
```

I don't want to create something like below

```
@MongoRepository
public interface IGenericReactorRepository extends ReactorCrudRepository<Vendor, ObjectId> { }
```

With this approach, I need to create a separate interface for each entity. How can I make this generic? So that in dependency injection I just pass the entity and type as like this `public record VendorService(IGenericReactorRepository<Vendor, ObjectId> iGenericReactorRepository)`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Micronaut Data need to know the actual entity at the compile-time to generate possible queries. The MongoDB integration doesn't need so many pre-generated queries like SQL support but that's how it works right now. Maybe we can provide a different way to access Criteria API operations not bound to the repository.